# Compare time in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I get a .csv file with values inside and one of the columns contains durations in the format hh:mm:ss for example 06:42:13 (6 hours, 42 minutes and 13 seconds). Now I want to compare this time with a given time for example 00:00:00 because I have to handle the information in that row different.

time is the value I got out of the .csv file

```
if time == 00:00:00:
  do something
else:
  do something different
```

Thats what I want but it obviously doesn't work how I did it.  I thought python stored the time as a String but when i compared it like this:

```
if time == "00:00:00":
```

it didn't work either.

Thats how I get the values out of the .csv file:

```
import csv
import_list = []
with open("input.csv", "r") as csvfile:
    inputreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in inputreader:
        import_list.append(row)
```

The .csv file looks like this:

```
Name; Duration; Tests; Warnings; Errors
Test1; 06:42:13; 2000; 2; 1
Test2; 00:00:00; 0; 0; 0
```

and so on.

Comment: Did you notice the space before the value? Maybe you just have to do a `.strip()` on the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
if time == " 00:00:00":
    ...
```

You have a trailing space at the beginning.
Alternatively you can change your code into this:

```
import csv
import_list = []
with open("input.csv", "r") as csvfile:
    inputreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in inputreader:
        import_list.append([item.strip() for item in row])
```

Comment: The delimiter in the question is `';'`

Comment: My mistake, used it from my file :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead:

```
if time.strip() == "00:00:00":
  do something
else:
  do something different
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing string comparisions, using inbuilt `datetime` library to create datetime objects. Use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to convert date string.

Comment: This won't solve the problem with trailing spaces, and is actually totally useless.